# Xamarin using cross platform 3D engine

Tags: xamarin, xna, cross-platform, monogame

I am a iOS / Android developer who has started to look at Xamarin for Business apps.  As a hobby I make the odd 3D game and one thing thats always got me is having to write it for 2 platforms (Yes I do know about Unity, not my bag)

Xamarin seem to recommend Monogame for 3D work and I have a test project working on iOS / Android (woo hoo).

However, I read that it uses XNA which has according to my .net friends has been dead for years.  I also  read that MonoGame is moving away from it.

Does anyone know anything about this?  If I want to use Xamarin and be cross platform, what should I be using for 3D rendering?

Is it worth trying XNA?

Comment: Questions asking for opinions and soliciting discussion are Off Topic.

Comment: Sorry, where would you advise I ask mate?

Comment: http://community.monogame.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Monogame** is an open source implementation of the XNA API. It uses the same classes and namespace than XNA but it is a `new implementation` that is cross-platform.

It used to require the XNA framework for its `content pipeline tool`. But since version 3.3, Monogame provides its own tool so `XNA is not required anymore`.

Comment: Thanks so I should not worry about it going away and use it

Comment: I think so. And for your information, XNA 4 samples can be easily used in Monogame. This is really helpful for learning.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this, really helpful mate!

Answer (score 3):

For anyone coming along later, Xamarin as of [Dec 2015](https://blog.xamarin.com/3d-game-engine-for-android-ios-and-net/) support the [Urho3D engine](http://urho3d.github.io/) with their [UrhoSharp](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/urho/introduction/) project which interfaces the C++ engine from C#.